# Dropdown image not appearing infront

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown having an image in place of arrow. But I am having a cross browsing issue. In chrome it is displaying fine but in mozilla the image is shown in the back. Attached is the screenshot.

Dropdown HTML

```
<td align="right">
 <div class="blue" style="float: left;">
    <div class="lightblueHeading" style="text-align: left;">No. Of Guests</div>
    <div>
        <div class="styled-select">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNoOfGuest" runat="server" Style="width: 165px;"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

Class

```
.styled-select
{
    overflow: hidden; /*height: 24px;     background: url(../images/dropdown_icon.png) no-repeat right;*/
    background: url(../images/signup-dropdown_icon.png) no-repeat right;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.styled-select select
{
    background: transparent; /*border: 1px solid #e8e9e9;*/
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    visibility: hidden;

}
```

[image: Chrome dropdown]

[image: Mozilla dropdown]

Comment: First of all, there's no such property as `opacity:hidden`. Either use `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`. Have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wHp3L/1/

Comment: By adding visibilty:hidden it removes the dropdown, therefore it is now unclickable.

Comment: Thank You. I have applied opacity: 0. It worked like a charm.

Comment: You may accept it as an answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity:0` as a property for your `select` tag.

Comment: This problem is solved but now by applying opacity:0, new problem occured :-).
The select text opacity also got invisible i.e. its opacity is also now 0. Is there anyway I can set the opacity of select 0 but not of the text?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are trying is not fully compatible in every browser and you are facing browser compatibility issue and some how you managed the problem but in future you may get face browser compatibility issues because there are lot of version of IE in market Everyone's favourite is IE7. So to over come from the problem my suggestion is to use jquery based plugin like below:

1. http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/
2. http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/